# cfdisk не предлагает мне выбрать disklabel type

Tags: linux, archlinux, gpt

с помощью cfdisk удалил всё с диска. теперь хочу создать разделы GPT, но при входе cfdisk не предлагает выбрать мне DiskLabel type?

Почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была аналогичная проблема. Диск был уже размечен, поэтому `cfdisk` не предлагал изменить таблицу. Почистил диск командой `wipefs --all [имя_диска, пример: /dev/sda]`

Answer (score 1):

А должен? Вы сами выбираете тип раздела. Или вы про что-то другое?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я по вашему идиот_))? видите наверху написано метка: dos вот что я хотел поменять, а не тип раздела

Comment: @Gybernaty А... Так вам тогда не cfdisk, а cgdisk надо использовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
man 3 mlabel

mlabel - make an MSDOS volume label
```